# I will apply to another Phd program, and I don't know how to explain my problem with my current program. (phd student)

Tags: phd, international-students, transfer-student

I posted my problem a few weeks ago here:
[My advisor has literally no idea what my research is about and I am freaking out (phd student)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/161828/my-advisor-has-literally-no-idea-what-my-research-is-about-and-i-am-freaking-out)

Now I am considering applying to another PhD program. I am going to go to the university and talk to them. However, I am not sure how to explain my problem without sounding like I am trying to trash my advisor (as explained, he is very nice, but he is not a specialist, and what is really making me want to change the program is that he doesn't know what my research is about).

Also, should I mention that in my SOP? How should I put it?

I am really worried that my advisor would know (people know each other, he might have contacts especially that both universities are in the same state. what if they call my university to ask? I am okay with that, but if I did not get in I'll be in a problem with my advisor).

Should I just say that I want to change the program because I am interested in prof.x work instead? What if he is not interested in my research? This would cost me my chances with other professors (while I really like his work, I need ro transfer and I really don't see him as my priority)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What do grad schools want to hear about why I'm changing PhD programs?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159128/what-do-grad-schools-want-to-hear-about-why-im-changing-phd-programs)

Comment: No not related. The reasons are different. I can easily say that I don't feel comfortable in the location. Saying you don't think your supervisor is interested is not easy and you might come across rude